# What is wrong with this loop in C?

Tags: c, loops

```
int i;
i=0;
for (i=0;i>2;i++)
    {
     repeat((3),"|",var);
     printf("\n");          
    }
```

For some reason it gets to the "for" and it skips it. I tried to put the `int i` outside of the for and even initialized it outside of the for and in debug it is zero.  all I need it to do is loop through this code twice.

Comment: You can set `i = 0`, and you can have the loop keep running while `i > 2`, but you can't do both and expect the loop block to be processed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change:

```
for (i=0;i>2;i++)
```

to:

```
for (i=0;i<2;i++)
```

You're testing if it's `> 2` which will fail so it never enters the loop.

Comment: Thanks, I did have at == and that was not working so I changed to > and still no difference

Answer (score 2):

It is because of your loop condition: `i > 2`

The variable `i` it is not greater than 2, so the condition `i > 2` will evaluate to 0 (FALSE)

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

```
for (i=0;i>2;i++)
```

you want

```
for (i=0;i<2;i++)
```

Otherwise your `for` loop body will never be executed.

Answer (score 1):

So lets break down a for loop.  There are three pieces for(piece1; piece2; piece3)

piece1 = setting of a variable, this will happen once at the first running of the loop

piece2 = while condition is true, continue to loop

peice3 = at the end of each iteration perform this action.

So your loop right now says first set i=0, while i is greater than 2 (which you just said it isn't)...at this point your compiler has already skipped out, because the condition will never be true.

Because of this, testing == won't work either, because that will make it loop while i is equal to 2, which will never be true because the only place you are updating i is within the loop.  The middle condition is not a break condition it is a continuation condition.

Answer (score -1):

Change you for loop to for (i=0;i<2;i++)

Comment: This really added something that the other answers didn't mention, don't you think?